# Why doesn't getComputedStyle take into account margin collapsing?

Tags: javascript, css, cssom

Concerning in-browser Javascript, the `window.getComputedStyle()` method is supposed to give the final used values of the CSS properties applied to an element. According to the [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/used_value), that means “after all calculations have been performed”.

However, it seems that “all calculations” does not include margin collapsing. In Firefox and Chrome (at least), the instruction `getComputedStyle().marginBottom` returns the computed value before any margin collapsing has been calculated.

For instance, consider the following element:

```
<div style="margin: 10px 0 15px 0"></div>
```

Its top and bottom margins will be collapsed because (roughly) its content height is zero (cf. [the W3C CSS2 Recommendation](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html#collapsing-margins)). The CSSOM methods will return these values:

```
getComputedStyle().marginTop → 10px
getComputedStyle().marginBottom → 15px
getBoundingClientRect().top → {top of margin box} + marginTop
getBoundingClientRect().bottom → idem top
```

But, due to margin collapsing, the layout shows a margin of 10px before the bounding client rectangle, and a margin of 5px after, i.e. `max(0, marginBottom - marginTop)`.

Why doesn't `getComputedStyle().marginBottom` return directly 5px, the real used value “after all calculations have been performed”, instead of the specified 15px? Is this a W3C-recommended behavior? (I haven't seen anything about this in the w3.org docs.)

Is this a bug or a feature?

Answer (score 1):

There's a distinction between *computed* and *used* values. Furthermore, `getComputedStyle()` returns *resolved* values, "which may either be the computed value or the used value". [MDN reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/used_value).

As for the practical value of the many calculation states, I don't know any.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see all of your code, but I think that the function name is actually, "getComputedStyle," with a "u".

A typo? Could it be that easy? You wouldn't be the first — myself included.

Hoping this helps.

Comment: Yes that was a typo. Thanks

Comment: But the question still stands ;-)